# Can this code be improved with the use of multithreading?

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await

I have a simple Windows service, which runs only once per day. It performs some queries in database, generates appropriate html content (tables, divs, ...) and sends it in body of an e-mail to multiple recipients.

The body of the e-mail is created like this:

```
private static string GenerateBody()
{
    using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
    using (var htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
    {
        htmlWriter.RenderBeginTag("html");
        htmlWriter.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Head);
        htmlWriter.WriteLine("<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" />");
        htmlWriter.RenderEndTag();
        htmlWriter.RenderBeginTag("body");

        htmlWriter.Write(
            new StringBuilder()
                .Append(OverviewParagraph.GenerateHTMLContent())
                .Append(PackageWeightParagraph.GenerateHTMLContent())
                .Append(BoxWeightParagraph.GenerateHTMLContent())
                .Append(CodeQualityParagraph.GenerateHTMLContent())
                .Append(ChecksParagraph.GenerateHTMLContent())
                .ToString()
        );

        htmlWriter.RenderEndTag();
        htmlWriter.RenderEndTag();

        return stringWriter.ToString();
    }
}
```

All the `GenerateHTMLContent` methods are pretty much the same - they execute a query in my database, build an HTML table with the help of a HTMLTextWriter and return the table as a string.

Can this code be improved with the use of multithreading or maybe async-await pattern? The code in question is where I append lines to the StringBuilder object.

EDIT: I asked the question because I never worked with multithreading before, just wanted to know if it is possible. Besides, the program runs fast enough now.

Comment: Is the code that calls this method in a loop? ie I'm guessing that you are looping round a list of recipients and calling the above code to generate emails, is this correct?

Comment: First step of refactoring could be to use one Using() than 2.
The other question is, do you know or think that those methods GenerateHTMLContent are time consuming operations? First have you done some benchmarks to know if they are really the showstoppers?

Comment: Very unlikely.  Threads help to avoid freezing a user interface (async/await) or buy you more CPU cycles on a multicore CPU.  A once-a-day program is unlikely to have a user interface.  And this code needs more dbase servers and network bandwidth, not cpu cycles.

Comment: @KevinHolditch - No, this runs only once. This method generates the body of an MailMessage. All the recipients get the same mail. And the recipients are added to the MailMessage object with MailMessage.To.Add("...") method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Parallel.Invoke(
    () => { var s = OverviewParagraph.GenerateHTMLContent(); lock (sb) sb.Append(s); },
    () => { var s = PackageWeightParagraph.GenerateHTMLContent(); lock (sb) sb.Append(s); },
    () => { var s = BoxWeightParagraph.GenerateHTMLContent(); lock (sb) sb.Append(s); },
    () => { var s = CodeQualityParagraph.GenerateHTMLContent(); lock (sb) sb.Append(s); },
    () => { var s = CodeQualityParagraph.GenerateHTMLContent(); lock (sb) sb.Append(s); }
);
```

Comment: Now let's assume we want the document sections to appear in a predictable order :)

Comment: Only if slobodan doesn't care in what order those parts are added to the output.

Comment: Then assign results to different variables & append to `sb` after `Parallel.Invoke` in any order you want

Answer (score 2):

If it is only generating one thing, parallelisation is complex as you need to consider synchronisation. Parallelisation is a more obvious candidate when you can perform *task* parallelisation (separate and isolated operations done in parallel). You also don't give enough information to indictate whether complex work is warranted:

- how long does it take now?
- is it a problem that it takes that time?

If there is a significant benefit (to justify significant effort) then sure! I strongly suspect, however, that the answer is "no", in which case, leave well alone. Handling multiple threads on a single operation is complex.

You could perhaps consider the separate document sections as parallel tasks, but HTML generation is usually pretty quick - so unless you have profiled this and know they take time, don't bother. Far more likely: your data query is the blockage. In which case, spend some time improving that, without worrying about parallelisation.

Answer (score 1):

If the `GenerateHTMLContent` methods are isolated ( i.e. they won't interfere with each other if run concurrently ), you could start them all off together and collect the results when they become available:

```
// start tasks
Task<string> overviewParagraph =
    Task.Factory.StartNew( () => OverviewParagraph.GenerateHTMLContent() );

Task<string> packageWeightParagraph =
    Task.Factory.StartNew( () => PackageWeightParagraph.GenerateHTMLContent() );

....

// collect results
string overviewParagraphHtml = overviewParagraph.Result;
string packageWeightParagraphHtml = packageWeightParagraph.Result;
...
```